# ReactJS simple hover works critical slow

Tags: reactjs

Here's whole class . This example works. No error in ts compiler no errors in browser logs .

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Label } from "../../components/label/label";
import IApp from "../../globals/interfaces";
import { Tap } from "../../globals/types";
import Services from "../../services/services";
import { HeaderI, HeaderStateI } from "./interface";
import { getMenuStyle, getMyStyle } from "./style";

export class Header extends React.Component<HeaderI, HeaderStateI, any> {

  public add = Services.addElement;

  private myRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  private myDOM: Element | Text;

  constructor(args: any) {
      super(args);
      this.state = {
        enabledComponent: true,
        visibility: true,
        debugView: false,
        elements: [],
        myStyle: getMyStyle(),
        menuStyle: getMenuStyle(),
        menuItemStyle: [getMenuStyle(), getMenuStyle()],
        menuIsOpen: false,
        myEvent: null,
      };
      this.myRef = React.createRef();
      this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  // Override func
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.myDOM  = this.myRef.current;
  }

  public render() {

    if ( this.state.visibility === true ) {

      return (
            <div ref={this.myRef} style={this.state.myStyle} >
            <Label myStyle={this.state.menuStyle}
                   name="headerName"
                   text="MENU"
                   onClick={this.clickEvent.bind(this)}
                   onMouseEnterHandler={this.hoverIn.bind(this)}
                   onMouseLeaveHandler={this.hoverOut.bind(this)} />
             {this.state.elements.map((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index) => {
               return <span ref={this.myRef} key={index} style={this.state.menuItemStyle[index]}
                           onClick={this.clickMenuItem.bind(this)}>{element}</span>;
             })}
            </div>
          );

    }

  }

  // Override func
  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any, prevState: any) {
      // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  }

  // Override func
  public componentWillUpdate(nextProps: any, nextState: any) {
    // We should not call setState !
    // if (nextState.open == true && this.state.open == false) {
    //   this.props.onWillOpen();
    // }
  }

  private adaptCss(e: CustomEvent) {
    // DEMO for css changes :
    // Collect (this of class instance)
    const self = e.detail.data.self;
    // Make any changes in css
    // Collect base or initial css
    const myStyle = getMyStyle();
    // Make changes
    myStyle.background = "yellow";
    // Setup state and nothing more
    self.setState({
      myStyle,
    });

  }

  private printMe() {
    // console.log("Layout Header is active and update is on");
  }

  private clickEvent(event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {

    if (this.state.menuIsOpen === false) {

      const myKey = "header.01";
      const element1Args: IApp.NewElementArgsI = {
        key: myKey,
        onClick: null,
        myStyle: null,
        content: "HOME",
        hoverIn: ((e) => this.hoverIn(e, myKey)),
        hoverOut: ((e) => this.hoverOut(e, myKey)),
      };
      const myKey2 = "header.02";
      const element2Args: IApp.NewElementArgsI = {
        key: myKey2,
        onClick: null,
        myStyle: null,
        content: "ABOUT",
        hoverIn: ((e) => this.hoverIn(e, myKey2)),
        hoverOut: ((e) => this.hoverOut(e, myKey2)),
      };

      this.add(element1Args);
      this.add(element2Args);

      // Set new state for menu
      this.setState(
        {menuIsOpen: !this.state.menuIsOpen},
      );

    } else {

      // Menu is already visible , delete menu items
      this.setState (
        {
          menuIsOpen: !this.state.menuIsOpen,
          elements: [],
        },
      );

    }

  }

  private clickMenuItem(event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {

    const t = event.target as HTMLDivElement;
    // Also possible to call event.target.textContent !
    switch (t.textContent) {
      case "HOME":
        this.props.provide({instruction: "show_home"});
        break;
      case "ABOUT":
        this.props.provide({instruction: "show_about"});
        break;
      default:
        console.warn("No case for cleckMenuItem in bodyCOntent class!");

    }

  }

  private hoverIn = (e: Tap, id: any) => {

    const styleArrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.menuItemStyle));

    this.state.elements.forEach((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index: number) => {

      if (id === element.key) {
          styleArrayCopy[index].color = "red";
      } else {
          styleArrayCopy[index].color = "initial";
      }

    });

    if (this.state.elements.length === 0) {

        const test = getMenuStyle();
        test.color = "lime";
        this.setState({
          menuItemStyle: styleArrayCopy,
          menuStyle: test,
        });

    } else {

      this.setState({
        menuItemStyle: styleArrayCopy,
      });

    }

  }

  private hoverOut = (e: Tap, id: any) => {

    this.state.elements.forEach((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index: number) => {

      if (id === element.key) {
        const styleArrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.menuItemStyle));
        styleArrayCopy[index].color = "initial";
        this.setState({
          menuItemStyle: styleArrayCopy,
        });
      }

    });

  }
}
```

I get style like that :

```
export function getMenuStyle(): IApp.MyMinimumCssInterface {
  return {
    display: "block",
    background: "#445566",
    height: "30px",
    width: "100%",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "inherits",
  } as IApp.MyMinimumCssInterface;
}
```

On hover in and out i have ~400ms delay . If i moving up/down there is no hover effect. This is so bad. What will be when i add large assets add more code...

I detect very slow executing in not just this example even most simple  example from reactJS tutorials ?!

I am also interested in React.ReactElement Object instance . Is it possible for OverRide some func - Like updateDid ?

***To missunderstund from comment This is from React site :***

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased
>   properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM
>   style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS
>   security holes. For example:

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};
```

I use it the same principle.

**Updated** , now looks like :

// Render

```
 {this.state.elements.map((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index) => {
     return <span ref={this.myRef} key={index} style={this.getStyle(element, index)} onClick={this.clickMenuItem.bind(this)}>{element}</span>;
      })}

  private hoverIn = (e: Tap, id: any) => {

    const local: boolean[] = [];

    this.state.elements.forEach((element: React.ReactElement<any>, index: number) => {

      if (id === element.key) {
        local.push(true);
      } else {
        local.push(false);
      }

    });
```

Any explanation ??

Comment: This could speed up your your hover effect https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Comment: How big are these styles `this.state.menuItemStyle` you are copying ? json parse and stringify aren't quick. i can't understand why you are doing that, why not use conditional css classes?

Comment: this.state.menuItemStyle is already CSSProperties[]  !

Comment: I agree with @dashton JSON call here to copy will be slow the bigger that reference is. instead you may want to dynamically add css classes to the html to flip between states instead of that full copy bind.

Comment: Yeap i wanna simple dynamic creating ! What is the alternative?

Comment: This object is soo small that any reason is funny ? I can make 500.000 times bigger object in JS and it will be faster than react hover ?! What to do , i need key access object ? Or access from html dom object?

Comment: Have you actually tried commenting out the JSON.parse/ stringify to see whether that is the source of the bottleneck?

Comment: This is only working way , if i put anything on right side in this.state = { FOO : MYPROP }  MYPROP becomes also readonly !  hoverOut is injected intro React.Element that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found solution for very slow work flows.

There is no connections with React at all.

I have global.css who's loading on begin. First i noticed that only text delay.
 I create text shadow and i most suspect on shadow but it was transition.

***This code is most expensively code was*** :

```
  -webkit-transition: color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);

  -moz-transition: color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);

  -o-transition: color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);

  transition: color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
```

I remove this part of code.
Maybe this answer will help somebody .